# Read lines from a multiple txt files into variables

Tags: python

I have multiple txt files in a directory where each txt file have few lines of hashes:

546516fdsfgbfdgbfdf

232321dfsfdsgfdgvfd

321656fdsfsffgfdgfd

I'm trying to read each line in all the txt files in the directory and then pass them to the "**hash**" variable And run the script every time anew in order to download the hash binary file.

```
import requests

f = open('*.txt')
    hash = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()

    params = {'apikey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'file': (hash)}
response = requests.get('https://www.test.com/file/download', params=params)

downloaded_file = response.content

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('/tmp/sample.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, reading all hashes will solve your problem. Try this, and take a look at the comments, too.

```
import os
import requests

# If text files aren't in the same dir, edit path as you see fit
path = os.getcwd()

# Reads all text files in current directory.
all_files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if i[-4:] == '.txt']
all_hashes = []

for file in all_files:
    with open(path+file,'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # Handling empty lines only here, add regex or more params to strip if needed
        if not line.strip('\n'):
            continue
        # All hashes are now stored in a list
        all_hashes.append(line.strip('\n'))

# Just iterate over the list and make requests
# You may want to add a delay with time.sleep() in the loop
for hash in all_hashes:
    params = {'apikey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'file': (hash)}
    response = requests.get('https://www.test.com/file/download', params=params)
    downloaded_file = response.content

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # you may want to use 'a' instead of 'wb' here?
        with open('/tmp/sample.bin', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Edit: Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964691/5070837) post which tells you how you can read all `txt` files from a directory, and at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43625375/5070837) one which shows how to read a file, line-by-line, into a list.

Comment: As a side note, you do not need to close your file if you open it with a `with` statement

Comment: I save all files in the same name: sample.bin.  do you know how to save the file in his original name?

Comment: First, is the above code helping you out? If yes, that's this question solved. 

Second, saving output by file-name would require you to keep a maintain a record of some sort, maybe a dict: `index_dict = {hash1: filename1, hash2:filename2, ... }`. Then you could use `with open('{0}.bin',format(index_dict[hash1]), 'a+' as f:` before you write your file.

Comment: @bugnet17 take a look at this meta [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers), please. It would be nice for new users to get motivation to answer more posts. Either downvote answers if they don't help when people aren't answering comments for those posts, or upvote/accept if they help.

Comment: When running the script  got the next error: 
with open(path+file,'r+') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/extract-hashestest.txt'

Comment: Can you post your directory tree, the one with the files, along with the pwd of the script?

Comment: root@ubuntu:/tmp/extract-hashes# pwd
/tmp/extract-hashes

Comment: Script and the files located in the same folder: /tmp/extract-hashes

Comment: Okay, could you copy-paste the output of the command `tree` while in `tmp/extract-hashes`? Also, your error indicates that `'/tmp/extract-hashestest.txt'` doesn't exist, are you sure that you've not forgotten to add a `/` between `extract-hases` and `test.txt` somewhere in your script? Maybe instead  of `path + file` in the file opening line, try `path+'/'+file`?

Comment: Now is OK but the script sends one HTTP request for all hashes. I need the script will send one HTTP request for each hash in the list.  any ideas?

Comment: The code I've posted above doesn't send one HTTP request for all hashes. It makes exactly _one_ `requests.get()` call for _each_ iteration of the `for hash in all_hashes` loop. That is why I'd suggested using `time.sleep()` so that you don't overload the server you're pinging and maintain API call etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just read the whole line into num, that will do the trick.

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('/tmp/file.bin', 'wb') as f:
        num = f.read()
```

Comment: OP wants to write output into the `file.bin`, as I see it, after making a request. You're reading from it, which doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As i was writing this answer, OP just wanted to write the content of file.bin to the variable num.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, I needed to change a certain String in every file of a folder if appearing.

**Important** This is a rather older script, so there are some to do's. I would recommend to resolve those issues as an exercise to improve the code quality:

- Using a try and raise Block if an Error occurs.
- Define regular expressions object instead of defining them in the line, the algorithm works faster with this
- Applying List Comprehensions

**Note** I use regex101.com for creating my regular expressions.

```
import os, fnmatch, re

allLinesString = []

def findReplace(directory, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            global i
                with open(filepath, "r") as f:
                    for line in f:
                    # So lets decide here what to do when we go through each line of each file found in the directory
                        if "String" in line:
                            # Okay and here we write the String if "String" is in line to an array
                            allLinesString.append(line)
                            # And if you want you can even use a regex expression to manipulate the "String" which you just found, or delete certain characters what so ever
                            # Or write the entry to a varible called num in your case
                            allLinesString[i] = re.sub(r'^\s', '', allLinesString[i])

# In this case the function searches for all markdown files for the specific string
if __name__ == '__main__':
    findReplace("wantedDirectoryPath/", "*.md")
```